# The implicit equation of the canonical Torus with inner radius $r$ and revolving radius $R$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In $R^3$, The implicit equation of the canonical Torus with inner radius $r$ and revolving radius $R$ is given by $$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2+z^2=r^2$$

what I understand from this equation (how do we get it) you take the equation of the circle of radius $R$ with the center at the origin  $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R=0$$ after that you look for  $z$ such that for any (x_0,y_0) you obtain a circle around this point this will give you
$$(\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}-R)^2+z^2=r^2$$ and now by taking all direction we obtain
$$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2+z^2=r^2$$
am I right or there is some other explanation how to get this equation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the circle $(x-R)^2 + z^2 = r^2$ in the $xz$-plane. Since $0<R-r\le x\le R+r$, when we form the surface of revolution obtained by rotating about the $z$-axis, this replaces $x$ with $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.